# django generate access token for api call

Tags: python, django

In my django system I want to generate `access_key` of specific length lets say 20. I want it to be unique.

I can pass `username` `email` which is unique related to user.

What I am doing now is something llike ...

`hashlib.sha1(some_random_value + username_or_email.encode('utf8') + l_salt).hexdigest()`

Problem here is .. It is giving me value of any length not specific length.

Is this good way to generate access_token or something else.. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check out [Django Rest Framework Token Auth](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication). Espesially if you are developing REST service.